# How to get the URL of all files in a directory of Firebase by Python

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, pyrebase

I have a directory (*wallpaper_app/Best_Wallpapers*) in storage of Firebase and it has some files. I want the URLs of all files.

But when I try to get list_files by

```
image = storage.child('wallpaper_app/Best_Wallpapers/').list_files()
```

I am facing an error:

```
  File "d:\Project\wallpaper-app-kivy\temp.py", line 33, in <module>
    imageUrl = storage.list_files()
  File "D:\Project\wallpaper-app-kivy\wallpaper-app\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 507, in list_files
    return self.bucket.list_blobs()
AttributeError: 'Storage' object has no attribute 'bucket'
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get a Service account.
Go to *Project settings* and then *Service accounts. in the *Firebase Admin SDK*.
Scroll down to make a new private key and download the file.

You have to pass its path of the file to configuration dict by the key of "serviceAccount".